# Bind a custom class of controls to Listview/GridView as ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I am facing some problem with binding the data to the controls in ListView/GridView as ListViweItem.

Requirement: Have to show a checkbox, Label, DropDown and a textbox per row which get data from all different sources.Here is the sample class:

```
class Data {
    public CheckBox chk_box;
    public Label lbl;
    public ComboBox cmb_box;
    public TextBox t_box;

    public Data(String lbl_Data,List<String> cmb_box_Data) {
        chk_box=new CheckBox();
        lbl=new Label();
        lbl.Content=lbl_Data;
        cmb_box=new ComboBox();
        cmb_box.ItemsSource=cmb_box_Data;
        chk_box.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(chk_box_clicked);
        ...
    }
    private void chk_box_clicked(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        if(chk_box.IsChecked == true) cmb_box.IsEnabled = false;
        else cmb_box.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Now i need to add this class' object as a ListViewItem, per control per column in ListView/GridView - dynamically, row by row and then after user makes selections access all the rows once again row by row and get values from these controls.

XAML code:

`<ListView  x:Name="TestGrid">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="  Select  "/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="  Label  "/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="  cmb_box  "/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="  t_box  "/>
             </GridView>
         </ListView.View>
    </ListView>`

Since, the Items Source for all the controls is different, i cannot use ListView.ItemsSorce to bind data. Please suggest suitable options, or ways to accomplish the desired UI. I would like to make everything out from the controls given in VS only without using a third party dll(if possible).

Thank you for your time and suggestions in advance.

Comment: You need to rethink this.  A class named Data should not have properties that are UI controls.  You are not binding data to to controls.

Comment: @Blam ...thank you for the comment. Anyway, I am binding data to the controls. I just want to know how to do so. 

`DataSet ds = ... //fetches all rows for a col that i need to bind //in combobox and i have a User defines List<String> for Label that
//i pass 1 by 1.

foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Table[0].Rows)
cmb_list.Add(dr.ItemsArray[0]);
Data temp=new Data(str_list[i],cmb_list);

ListView_main.Items.Add(Data); //How to show these controls??`

Above thing loops the number to the number of elements in user-defined list. If there is some other way to to that please suggest me.

Comment: No, you have multiple UI controls in Data.   That is a bad design.   The UI controls should be in XAML data in data.

Comment: @blam ...thank you for your feedback. Will try and improve the design and i got what you meant earlier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check msdn.microsoft.com for binding

```
public class Datum
{
    public bool Select { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Select">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Select, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode= OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @Blam... thank you for the solution. Will try and implement the above solution and respond asap! Thank you for your reply

Comment: @Blam... i modified some things and now i can display all the things needed easily. Thank you for your suggestions. But the 2nd part is still not clear to me, how will I access all the ListViewItems' columns for each row for all these different controls when i have to read data after user selection/editing operation. Please suggest me with something for that too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suspect English is not a first language but you are not clear.  I think you need INotifyPropertyChanged.